# MySQL: Sub-select not returning expected COUNT result

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have the below query and it runs and processes ok, the problem is that the sub-select only ever returns either 1 or 0 when it should return a `COUNT` of all records that are within the past 24 hours as specified in the `WHERE` clause and also that all fall under the sub-selects criteria.

I suspect the issues is with the sub-select only comparing on `ID` at a time but I tried changing `WHERE tbr.ID = ID` to `WHERE tbr.ID IN (ID)` but it's still only returning 1 or 0.

The `COUNT` on the alias total returns 728 so the data does exist and is valid for the past 24 hours, this has been verified.

```
SELECT COUNT(tbr.`ID`) AS `total`
, (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `cred` WHERE tbr.`ID` = `ID` AND `match` = 'EXACT' AND `number` <> '') AS `exact`
, DATE(NOW()) AS `reportDate`
FROM `cred` tbr
WHERE tbr.`processed` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a conditional aggregate would help.

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(tbr.`ID`) AS `total`
 , COUNT(case when match` = 'EXACT' AND `number` <> '' then tbr.`ID` end) AS `exact`
 , DATE (NOW()) AS `reportDate`
FROM `cred` tbr
WHERE  tbr.`processed` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Sample data and expected result assist in choosing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(tbr.`ID`) AS `total`
, (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) 
    FROM `cred` 
    WHERE `ID` IN (tbr.`ID`)    --try with inverting this condition
        AND `match` = 'EXACT' 
        AND `number` <> '') AS `exact`
, DATE(NOW()) AS `reportDate`
FROM 
    `cred` tbr
WHERE 
    tbr.`processed` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```